# joint state publisher's zeros parameter

Tags: ros, joint-state-publisher, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

Could somebody please provide me a correct yaml file for ros joint state publisher's zeros parameter?

In the description of [joint_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher) it is written:

```
zeros (Dict mapping Strings to Floats, default: {})

Dictionary to specify some joints' 'zero position' (since hydro)
```

I thought of something like this, but it's not working:

```
zeros:
joint1: {0.5}
joint2: {0.6}
```

Here you have the [joint state publisher's code](https://github.com/ros/robot_model/blob/indigo-devel/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210153/joint-state-publisher%27s-zeros-parameter/) by [TkrA](https://answers.ros.org/users/22544/tkra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2015-05-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two ways to get a dictionary (key, value) on the ROS parameter server: loading a correctly formatted yaml file, or in-line in a `rosparam` for the `node` (in this case, `joint_state_publisher`).

> ```
> zeros:
> ```

```
joint1: {0.5}
joint2: {0.6}
```

If that is the actual formatting, then that won't work in either case. The whole `zeros` parameter should be a dictionary, not its individual elements (which you are doing by adding the curly braces (`{`, `}`).

In a yaml (note indentation):

```
zeros:
  joint1: 0.5
  joint2: 0.6
```

in-line in launch file:

```
<node type="joint_state_publisher" ..>
  <rosparam>
    zeros:
      joint1: 0.5
      joint2: 0.6
  </rosparam>
</node>
```

In both cases indentation is required for the parser to create a proper dictionary out of the yaml.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TkrA](https://answers.ros.org/users/22544/tkra/) on 2015-05-29**:
Ok, thanks!
It is working, i used

to load it in my launchfile.

**Comment by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) on 2018-12-13**:
This documented here: http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher